# User does not have bigquery.datasets.update permission

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have created a dataset in Google BigQuery and downloaded the json auth file. I am trying to access tables in this dataset from python in a Jupyter Notebook, but I am getting the error:

"Forbidden: 403 PATCH https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/testdbt-bigquery-20200403/datasets/landing_zone_flights: Access Denied: Dataset testdbt-bigquery-20200403:landing_zone_flights: User does not have bigquery.datasets.update permission for dataset testdbt-bigquery-20200403:landing_zone_flights."

Code:

```
%reload_ext google.cloud.bigquery

import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
print(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']) 
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('~/Code/BigQuery/Test_BQ.json')
#get dataset and set permissions as Reader
dataset = client.get_dataset("landing_zone_flights")
entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
full_dataset_id = "{}.{}".format(dataset.project, dataset.dataset_id)
dataset.access_entries = entries

dataset = client.update_dataset(dataset, ["access_entries"])  # Make an API request.

print(
    "Updated dataset '{}' with modified user permissions.".format(full_dataset_id)
)
```

The error is:

> Forbidden: 403 PATCH
>   https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/testdbt-bigquery-20200403/datasets/landing_zone_flights:
>   Access Denied: Dataset testdbt-bigquery-20200403:landing_zone_flights:
>   User does not have bigquery.datasets.update permission for dataset
>   testdbt-bigquery-20200403:landing_zone_flights
>   .

What am I doing wrong? I'm able to get and list the dataset properties but unable to update or query any tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the warning message "User does not have bigquery.datasets.update permission for dataset testdbt-bigquery-20200403:landing_zone_flights", it is understood that you need access to the dataset that requires to update METADATA inside the table, so ideally you will have to find the GCP Role being required to perform "Update" operation on the dataset, so the required role is "BigQuery Data Editor" i.e. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.dataEditor, which needs to be mapped at DATASET LEVEL.

As a part of *Best Practice*, follow the below outline steps for your requirement.

BigQuery -> Click on dataset -> Sharing->Permissions->Add Principal;
Under "Add Principals" - "Provide your Service Account name" and whereas under "Assign Roles", choose "BigQuery Data Editor", and then SAVE.

This way, you will follow the best practices of GCP Security by satisfying the least "privileged access management" which helps in avoiding the accidental access of unnecessary resources.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [this Google Cloud link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-basic-roles?hl=en&_ga=2.99188510.-12734616.1626689293)
2. Go to Google Console
3. Change the permission for the project from "editor" to "owner".
4. Follow the latest instructions—but as of the time of this writing, I went for the IAM role to change the permissions.

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by creating a new key with the role Project - Owner, rather than BigQuery - Reader

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a more granular approach of allowing update in Bigquery dataset, you can use the following rules:

1. bigquery.datasets.create
2. bigquery.datasets.delete
3. bigquery.datasets.update
4. bigquery.datasets.get

This predefined roles is mentioned in [there](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).